# Why is the lebesgue measure of an irrational vector infinte?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

As part of a proof it is stated (without explanation) that the Lebesgue measure of a $x
\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathbb{Q}^n$ is infinite.

I cannot see why? Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to explain this. Easiest is to notice that Leb $\mathbb{Q}^n=0$, for all $n=1,2,\ldots$.
Since $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable, we can express each $p_i\in \mathbb{Q}^n$ as 
$$p_i=(q^i_1,q^i_2,\ldots ,q^i_n),$$
where $i=1,2,\ldots$ and $q_j^i\in \mathbb{Q}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots ,n$ and knowing that Lebesgue measure of each rational number is $0$:
\begin{align*}
\text{Leb }\mathbb{Q}^n&=\text{Leb } p_1+\text{Leb } p_2+\ldots\\
&=\text{Leb }q^1_1+\ldots +\text{Leb }q^1_n+\text{Leb }q_1^2+\ldots +\text{Leb }q_n^2+\ldots \\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Since Leb $\mathbb{R}^n=\infty$, it follows: Leb $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathbb{Q}^n=\infty$.